# Use of a subsequence in proving the extrem value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Dear reader of this post,

I would like to ask a question about the use of a subsequence in the prove of the extrem value theorem. In order avoid any confusion, I will first state the claim I am looking at:

Show that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \leq b$, and any real value function $f \in \mathcal{C}[a,b] $ ($\mathcal{C}$ is the set of continuous functions), there exist $x,y \in [a,b] $ such that $f(x) \geq f(t) \geq f(y) $ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Again in order to not raise any confusion I will sketch the proof although I realize that I am in serious danger of making the advanced reader fall asleep. Denote the supremum of $f$ as  $A = f(x)$.  Because the function is real valued, one knows that there exists a sequence $h_n \in \mathbb{R} $ with $h_n \rightarrow A$. Now construct the sequence $(x_n)  \in [a,b] $ with $f(x_n) = h_n$. As the sequence $x_n $ is bounded there exists a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ converging to $x$. As $f \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ one knows that $f\left(x_{n_{k}}\right) \rightarrow  f(x) = A$.

The question I am thinking about is: What is the use of the subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$. Phrased another way: What would happen is there was no such subsequence? (I know that this violates the Bolzano-Weiterstrass sentence, I am more interested in understanding the relevance of the subsequence for proving the extreme value theorem.)

I am looking forward for your replies.

Comment: Just because there exists a sequence $h_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $h_n \to A$ doesn't mean that there exists $(x_n)$ with $f(x_n) = h_n$.  For instance, if any of the $h_i$s are larger than $A$, we will not be able to find a corresponding $x_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As pointed out, the logic is that there are points $x_n$ such that $h_n=f(x_n)\to A$ - and this defines $h_n$ - but this doesn't affect anything.)

It's easy to see why the idea of a subsequence is important. Consider

$$f(x)=-e^{-x},\qquad f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$$

noting that Bolzano-W. fails for the whole real line.

Now the supermum is defined (as it happens) and is 0. We can take $x_n=n$ with $f(x_n)\to 0$. However, there is no convergent subsequence - essentially the real line is too big. (It's not *compact*.)

Comment: Dear Sharkos and dear @Goos: Thank you very much for your reply. I think I do not really understand your answers.  I defined A as the supremum thus I know that all other values $h_n \leq A$. As I generated $x_n : h_n = f(x_n) $ I know that all $f(x_n) \leq A $ and by saying that $x: f(x) = A$ I should have complete the prove. What part is flawed in my argumentation / could you please outline your answer a bit?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=1$ . If I'm allowed to pick some sequence $h_n =1+1/n$  then there are no corresponding $x_n$. You have to choose the $x_n$ "at the same time" as $h_n$. The definition of suprema tells you that there are $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)\to A$, it says nothing about some random $h_n$. But as I said this isn't directly relevant to the question you asked.

Comment: Dear Sharkos and dear @Goos: I think I now understand what you mean. Thank you very much for your answers.